# React Native Expo camera uses wide angle

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-camera

I am using the [Expo camera](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v44.0.0/sdk/camera/) in my React Native application for my web application.

Whenever I open the web application from any browser from my mobile device (Samsung Galaxy S10), it uses a wide-angle camera.

I'd like the webapp to use the "normal" back camera. Is there a way to define this?

```js
<Camera 
 ref={cameraRef}
 style={styles.camera}
 focusDepth='1'
 ratio='4:3'
>
```

Comment: Did you checked the picturesize and ratio or changed the zoom props? may its only look like wideangle

Comment: @Gismo1337 I have set the ratio to '4:3' and didn't modify the picturesize / zoom props. I am 100% sure it is using the wide angle camera of my phone

Comment: Start an issue: https://github.com/expo/expo/labels/Camera

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Expo Camera doesn't support selecting which lens to use. An alternative is to use is [react-native-vision-camera](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera)

Comment: This one is not comptable with Expo, right?

Comment: It has instructions on the getting started for Expo, so I assume so: https://mrousavy.com/react-native-vision-camera/docs/guides/

Comment: if you use EAS, don't worry about whether or not it's supported with Expo.  https://medium.com/p/6df148b888ce